# How call this backend coding?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Lets say I've following table:
**Table**: Posts
**Fields**: id, name, content

And another table:
**Table**: Images
**Fields**: id, post_id, url

Normally, I can create CRUD for each of them. User first create post and save it. Then by Images table CRUD user can add as many as images to posts. But what if requirement is no create CRUD for images. But inside Posts CRUD. I mean while creating (filling Posts fields) there is button which labeled "add images". Then when user add images via that button. Finally when press on "create post" backend code should create both posts and images. How you call it? I couldn't find any tutorial and lesson because of my English I couldn't describe it enough on Google search.

Comment: In your create method pop the images from post request, then create post first and then create images with poped data

Comment: please upload your CRUD method.

Comment: In Django: If your post_id is a ForeinKey to Posts you can checkout Inlines in the admin, which does this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inlines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to implement what you want in django admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Images

class PostsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Posts, PostsAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks. Magic word is "inline admin" I guess. But I wonder how it works. While creating Posts, its not written in Posts table right? Which means it's currently haven't ID. Then while you adding images how post_id in Image table gets value?

Comment: @Gereltod you are welcome. Yes, django inline admin are keywords. Not sure about how it was implemented, it is just django's magic:)